# AFNetworking fail with response.statusCode 0

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

I want to get address from latitude and longitude with GoogleGEO CODING (EX URL = http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true_or_false )

So I want to get JSON from that page by AFNetworking.
It's my code below :

```
IBAction)reLocation:(UIButton*)sender
{
    if(sender.tag==1)
    {
        NSArray *gpsValue = [self getGPS];

    float lat = [[gpsValue objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];
    float lon = [[gpsValue objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];

    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@,%@&sensor=true_or_false",GEOCODING_URL,[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", lat],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",lon]]; //        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", myFloat];
    NSLog(string);
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
    {
        NSLog(@"AFNetworking success");
        NSDictionary *location = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;

        // 3
        self.title = @"JSON Retrieved";
        //[self.tableView reloadData];
        NSLog(responseObject);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"AFNetworking failure");
        switch (operation.response.statusCode) {
            case 400:
                // Do stuff
                NSLog(@"error 400");
                break;
            default:
                NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)operation.response.statusCode]);
                break;
        }
        // 4
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving Weather"
                                                            message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }];

    // 5
    [operation start];


}}
```

But when I click my button, always afnetworking fails and log shows 0 for status code.

I also got url log that i put in
i already checked that url is not problem (it shows json in working order)

I debug with simulator!

Is there something I miss ?

Comment: Sometimes simulator connection is lost, restart the simulator.